# Dynamic table with headings and subheadings taken from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am echoing a list of areas covered as hypertext links taken from a database,

```
$area_shire = '';
$area_district = '';
$area_name = '';

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    if ($rows['area_shire'] != $area_shire) {
        $area_shire = $rows['area_shire'];
        $area_shire_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_shire);
        echo '<h2><a href=Driveway_Cleaning_'.$area_shire_url.'>'.$area_shire.'</a></h2><br>';
    }  


    if ($rows['area_district'] != $area_district) {
        $area_district = $rows['area_district'];
        $area_district_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_district);
        echo '<h3><a href=Driveway_Cleaning_'.$area_district_url.'>'.$area_district.'</a></h3><br>';

    }  


    if ($rows['area_name'] != $area_name) {
        $area_name = $rows['area_name'];
        $area_name_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_name);
        echo '<a href=Driveway_Cleaning_'.$area_name_url.'>'.$area_name.'</a><br>';
    }  
    }
?>
```

This is Giving me a linear output of

### West Midlands

#### Birmingham

Harborne
Edgbaston
Moseley

#### Dudley

Halesowen
Sedgley

### Warwickshire

I am trying to put the output into a dynamic table so each area_district (e.g) Dudley starts in a new column and is therefore to the right of Birmingham rather than below. Everything i try is affecting the order of the output. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the query to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to use an HTML table then? Or put each grouping in a flaoting div to where they can be placed along side each other?  My main recommendation is just work out your HTML template first, then work out how to inject the dynamic data into it afterwards.